# Azure B2C User Flow with API Connector not working on sign-up

Tags: azure, connector, azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure B2C to manage our users. Users will also be stored in a database where their roles are managed. We want to add the roles from the database to our claims, so we wanted to use an API connector for that. We are using the Sign up Sign in User Flow, so no custom policy. We have created an endpoint for Azure to call, added a custom User Attribute 'Roles' that we want to return as claim in our User Flow (so it's not collected as user attribute) and assigned the API connector to the flow "Before including claims".

When we run this User Flow, it works perfectly when we try to sign in with an existing account or with a federated user provider. However, when we try to register with a local account, we get a very vague error:
[image: Azure B2C Error]

When trying to debug it, it seems that our endpoint is never hit when following this scenario. I don't see any error in our API logs. The error code in the MS docs mentions this: **The claims exchange '{0}' specified in step '{1}' returned HTTP error response with Code '{2}' and Reason '{3}'.** But no idea what it is actually tring to say here... We are also certain it must have something to do with the API connector, since the sign up also works flawlessly when we disable the API connector. Any idea what the issue here might be, or any further steps we can take to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the error myself. The ObjectId isn't sent to the API on sign up, which we were requesting. I refactored to using only the e-mail address and now all calls come through.